# how do I plot ln[sinh (x)] and its derivate?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

how do I plot ln[sinh (x)] and its derivate (Cothx)?
I tried several times with

```
Plot[{Ln[sinh[x]], Coth[x]}, {x, -5, 5}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"},
     PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

but the graph only shows me coth x

Comment: What code did you use?

Comment: Plot[{Ln[sinh[x]], Coth[x]}, {x, -5, 5}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]

Comment: 1. `Log[]` is the function for the natural logarithm in *Mathematica*, and not `Ln[]`. 2. Capitalization matters, so `sinh[x]` would not work, but `Sinh[x]` would. 3. Whenever you ask a question on why something does not work, it is good practice here to include the code in the question to begin with, instead of having to be nudged by other people.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Plot[{Log[Sinh[x]], Coth[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]